# Let $V$ be a finite linear space and $S,T : V \to V$ linear transformations then $KerTS \subseteq KerS$ and $2$ more statements (True or false)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite linear space and $S,T : V \to V$ linear transformations then:
>
> 1. $KerTS \subseteq KerS$
> 2. if $KerS= \{0\}$ then $ImTS=ImT$
> 3. if $KerT= \{0\}$ then $ImTS=ImT$

---

the first statement is not true , I don't know the exact explanation but I saw in the book that $dimkerTS \geq dimKerS$ so from here I assumed that it is not correct

the second statement is true according to the textbook(but the textbook doesn't have proofs) so Given $KerS=0$ we have $KerS=0 \iff S=0$  we need to prove that $ImTS=ImT$

since $V$ is finite we have $dimV=n$ and according to the given information we get $dimKerS+dimImS=dimV=n$  $\iff$ $0+dimImS=dimV=n$ $\iff$ $ImS=V$ and $T(ImS)=ImTS=ImT$ I thought this will lead me to something but I cannot see how to continue I tried $T(v)=ImT\not=0$ because $dimImS\not=0$  but at this point I felt like I am just randomly trying stuff.

Appreciate any tips and help Thank you!

Comment: The first statement should be reversed

Comment: @FShrike $KerS \subseteq KerTS$? because if $u \in KerS$ then $S(u)=0$ therefore $T(S(u))=T(0)=0$?

Comment: Yes! Statement $2$ is correct - for finite dimensional algebra only - statement three is incorrect as written as far as I can tell (e.g. take $S$ to be the $0$ matrix)

Comment: @FShrike Sorry for the questions but wouldn't taking $S$ to be the zero matrix actually give us $ImTS=ImT$?

Comment: No! It would give $\forall x\in V,\,TSv=T(Sv)=T(0)=0$ so that the image of $TS$ is just $\{0\}$ which stands in contradiction to $\ker T=\{0\}$

Comment: @FShrike I am trying to understand it but I keep going back to the dimensions. as you said $\forall v \in V$ we get $T(S(v))=T(0)=0$ from here we get $ImTS=0=ImT$ so it is a contradiction because $dimKerT+dimImT=n$ but $dimkerT=0$ and $dimImT=0$ so $dimKerT+dimImT \not= n$?